# Gates and Policies are not working together

Tags: php, laravel, acl

I am creating an ACL using Gates and Policies. It's simple... In my application there are 3 managers, Adm, Mod and Finance.

I have a table of users and roles, in a one-to-many relationship, in users there is the role_id field.

I did it that way as it is in the code, but it doesn't work either in the middlewares or in the controllers

The actions are done anyway, it seems that there is no gate...

Gates:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        // Gate do Administrador (CRUD completo)
        Gate::define('administrador', [UserPolicy::class, 'viewAny', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete']);

        // Gate do Financeiro Edit
        Gate::define('financeiro-edit', [UserPolicy::class, 'view', 'viewAny', 'update']);

        // Gate do Financeiro Delete
        Gate::define('financeiro-delete', [UserPolicy::class, 'view', 'viewAny', 'delete']);

        // Gate do Moderador
        Gate::define('moderador', [UserPolicy::class, 'view', 'viewAny']);
        

    }
}
```

Policies

```
class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     */
    public function create(User $user): bool
    {
        return $user->role_id === 1;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 3]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     */
    public function delete(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 4]);
    }

}class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     */
    public function create(User $user): bool
    {
        return $user->role_id === 1;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 3]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     */
    public function delete(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1, 4]);
    }

}
```

I tried applying only Policies, either through middlewares or within controllers using `Gate::allows()` and so on.

I also attempted to apply only Gates, but it didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work" is vague, please add more infos. Any error on log?